# How to request write permission using Firebase Twitter Login

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I'm integrating Firebase Twitter Login into my web app. The idea is to allow users login to my app with their twitter account. I'm using Firebase on the backend, and it supports Twitter login out of the box.
The problem that I'm facing is that firebase requests 'read-only' permission for some reason. I need 'write' permission as well.

Here's my setup:
- created an app on Twitter and selected "Read and Write" access
- setup Firebase Twitter Auth according to the instructions

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
  console.log(result.credential);
  if (result.credential === undefined) {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("Login error");
});
```

When the user gets redirected to Twitter to login, Twitter says that the app will not be able to post any tweets. Once the user logs in, my app does show up as "read-only" in Settings->Apps.

[image: My Twitter App settings]

[image: What the user sees in their app settings once they authorize access to my app]